# C scope overlapping

Tags: c, scope, language-lawyer

The C standard states (emphasis mine):

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes **might** overlap. [...]

(section 6.2.1.4 from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

When can an identifier refer to two different entities but their scopes do not overlap?

Or, put differently, why is there the word "might" in the quote?

Comment: the answer lies right after the sentence you quoted...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I think the OP's question is, why does it not say "the scopes *will* overlap"? The word "might" implies that the scopes also might *not* overlap, and the question is about how that could be the case.

Comment: @bnaecker Yes, that is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: `{ { int i; } { int i; } }` block scoping in the same namespace (identifiers) but no overlapping.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès But how will the identifier designate two different entities?

Comment: it does designate two different entities. I think Jean has got you an answer.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Or by saying "an identifier designates two different entities" the standard means that the entities are searched everywhere, disregarding their scope?

Comment: In 6.2.1.2, there is the following: "[...] Different entities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces. [...]". I believe this means that an entity is "designated" by its identifier regardless of the location of the identifier with respect to the entity, therefore @Jean-BaptisteYunès is right.

Comment: `{ { int i; } { int i; } }` each `i` trivially designates a different entity (block scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These scopes for `name` overlap:

```
int f(void) {
  int name = 4;
  {
     int name = 6;
  }
}
```

These ones do not overlap:

```
int f(void) {
  {
     int name = 4;
  }
  {
     int name = 6;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I now understand the quote. Initially I thought that "If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space [...]" meant that **at a certain point in the program** an identifier "designates" two different entities, therefore I didn't see how their scopes could not overlap in that situation.

Comment: @user42768 at any point in a program, a given name designates at most one entity in a given name space, because of the scoping rules. Before scope is applied, no claim can be made about what a name designates *at a certain point*. The quote is referring to possible designations without respect to scope.

Comment: The scopes are not the same though.

Answer (score 3):

Read it as “The scopes might overlap, if an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space.” That is, the sentence is saying the scopes might overlap, and it is explaining the condition for which that occurs. English is unfortunately imprecise. This sentence is not meant to express the logic statement that if an identifier designates two entities in the same name space, there exist programs in which they overlap and there exist programs in which they do not. It expresses the fact that scopes might overlap and the fact that this occurs when an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space.

Comment: The explanation is either this (but I think the meaning of the quote is changed in a significant manner if we interpret it this way) or in the comment made by @Jean-BaptisteYunès. The standard may consider that if there are two entities with the same name (regardless of their location) their shared identifier "designates" them.

Comment: That's the answer.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès So is Eric Postpischil's answer the correct one or is it yours? I am inclined to believe it is yours, given the other quote (from 6.2.1.2) that I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: That's on your side! As mine is a comment you can grade both ;-)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Does reading Eric Postpischil's answer change your opinion regarding the correct interpretation of the standard or does it stay the same? The standard, at least to me, seems ambiguous with respect to the "designate" wording. In 6.2.1.1 it says: "The same identifier can denote different entities at different points in the program.". If the correct interpretation was the one in Eric Postpischil's answer, I believe the paragraph should have been: "If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space **at the same point in the program** [...]".

Comment: No an identifier cannot designates two different entities at the same point of the code! At a given time/location a given identifier designates only one entity. But there can exists same identifiers each designating different entities whatever their respective scope are. `{ int i; {int i;} }` overlapping, `{ int i; } { int i; }` not overlapping. In both cases, each `i` designates a different entity.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Ok, therefore this part of Eric Postpischil's answer: "It expresses the fact that scopes might overlap and the fact that this occurs when an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space." is not correct. Am I right?

Comment: @user42768: “6.2.1.1” refers to a non-existent clause. You mean “6.2.1 1”, which is paragraph 1 of clause 6.2.1.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: In 6.2.1 2, the standard says “Different identities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different names spaces.” As used here “designating an identifier” is not restricted to a particular point in the code; it is a global property spanning the entire program. If there are 20 definitions for something called `x` in the code that refer to 20 different entities, then `x` designates 20 different entities. Conversely, in 6.2.1 4, “Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity…”, so designating is specific to location.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Therefore, the standard does not use “designate” in a single, consistent way, and we cannot rely on such a single usage to interpret text. We have to figure out each use of “designate” in the standard separately.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I noticed this ambiguity, as I said in the above comment. However, I still believe that in: "If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. [...]", the "global" sense of "designate" is used. Therefore, if there are two entities with the same name, their scopes may or may not overlap. But if they do overlap, the rest of the paragraph dictates that the scopes must be nested.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So, to conclude, if the word "designate" is used with its "global" meaning in the quote from my original question ("If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap."), then the word "might" actually means that the scopes of the entities may or may not overlap. Is this correct?

Comment: @EricPostpischil So do we have a consensus that indeed the word "might" refers to the fact that there are situations in which the scopes overlap and other situations in which the scopes don't overlap? Because the "global" meaning of the word "designates" is used in the quote?

Answer (score 0):

I think the word might refer to possibilty of the general case rather than probability of hapening (that means is allowed to happen and when it happens there would be an overlap).
And the following lines indactes that by telling what happens in this case (the inner scope would be a strict subscope of the outer one and in this scope we will be using the intety defined inside this inner scope